# Graceful shutdown of celery workers with systemd?

Tags: systemd, celery

I have a box with celery workers, some of which perform reasonably long-running tasks (a few minutes). When this box updates, I'd like to shutdown the celery workers gracefully, so that ideally:

1. New tasks stop being sent to workers
2. Existing tasks are allowed to complete (with some timeout)
3. The workers are finally killed, and the new workers started

I'm using systemd to manage services on my Ubuntu box. Here's my conf file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=celery
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/var/app/celery/
ExecStart=/var/app/celery/run_celery.sh
ExecStop=/var/app/celery/stop_celery.sh
Nice=1
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The run_celery.sh script contains (in brief):

```
celery multi start 2 -A my_app --pidfile=/tmp/celery-%n.pid
```

And stop_celery.sh contains:

```
celery multi stopwait 2 --pidfile=/tmp/celery-%n.pid
```

However when I stop the script using systemctl, tasks are killed, rather than allowing workers to finish. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to set `TimeoutStopSec=` to what you want the timeout to be.  See the `systemd.service` man page for more in-depth information.